# Creating normalised playlists in Linux

Tags: linux, music, playlists

Is there a media/music player that will allow me to normalise the songs in a playlist?

Should also specify that I'd rather not have to alter the files - a program/plugin where the sound levels are stored as metadata would be preferable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Amarok can do this for you, with the 'replay_gain' plugin. Look here for more info:
http://jopsen.dk/blog/2007/08/volume-normalization-with-amarok/

On top of that, it's an all-round awesome music player ;)

Answer (score 4):

You can normalize the volume of sound files with [`SoX`](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) quite easily.
It is dubbed the Swiss Army knife of sound processing programs and has a lot of options.

There is also `normalize` and it is used like this:

```
normalize -b file1.wav file2.wav file3.wav
```

I haven't used normalize myself however.

However SoX and `normalize` work by modifying the audio data.
If you don't want that you can try [regain](http://abhinandh.com/normalize-volume-in-linux-with-mp3gain/). It still modifies the audio files but only the meta data.

Comment: SoX looks cool, not quite what I'm after though (have updated question)

Comment: OK, then maybe replaygain is what you are after (have updated the answer:-)

Answer (score 2):

**replaygain** is the way to go as it doesn't alter files, it just add the normalize information as metadata.
The only problem left is that you need a player which supports replaygain.